# XmlHttpRequest sends wrong JSESSIONID

Tags: angular, rest, spring-security, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send a file to my Backend using a XMLHttpRequest. In the Backend I am using spring security. The frontend uses Angular 2. The problem is that the XMLHttpRequest sends a totally different JSESSIONID Cookie(always the same one) and gets denied access. My other requests that are using Angular's `http.post` sent the correct JSESSIONID. The wrong JSESSIONID appears seemingly out of nowhere and I am unable to pinpoint the cause.

This is my XMLHttpRequest:

```
  postFormData() {
      return fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let formData: any = new FormData()
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

      formData.append("file", this.file, this.file.name);

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
              if (xhr.status === 200) {
              resolve(xhr.response)
          } else {
              reject(xhr.response)
      }
  }};


  console.log("sending stuff")
  //xhr.setRequestHeader();
  xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:8080/import/loadsheets', true);
  //xhr.setRequestHeader("withCredentials","true");
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  //xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  //let sess = this.cookieService.get("cookie");
  //console.log('Cookie: ', sess);
  //xhr.setRequestHeader('Cookie', sess);
  xhr.send(formData)
}));
}
```

This is the preflight:
[image]

And this is the actual request (with the wrong JSESSIONID):
[image]

What could the problem be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For one thing you want to remove the 'xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")' line. All 'Access-Control-Allow-\*' headers are response headers—you never want to send them in a request. The only affect you’ll ever have by doing that is to trigger the browser to do an unnecessary preflight. For the same reason, having the server include all the 'Access-Control-Allow-\*' header names in the value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' response header is also unnecessary. As is including 'withCredentials' in that header. You don’t need 'Origin' or 'Accept' in their either…